# StackOverflowError for coin change in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm writing a recursive function for the [Coin (change) problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) in Scala.

My implementation breaks with StackOverflowError and I can't figure out why it happens.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.tail(List.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.tail(List.scala:356)
    at recfun.Main$.recurs$1(Main.scala:58) // repeat this line over and over
```

this is my call:

```
  println(countChange(20, List(1,5,10)))
```

this is my definition:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int =  {

  def recurs(money: Int, coins: List[Int], combos: Int): Int = 
  {    
      if (coins.isEmpty)
          combos
      else if (money==0)
          combos + 1
      else
          recurs(money,coins.tail,combos+1) + recurs(money-coins.head,coins,combos+1)

  }
  recurs(money, coins, 0)
}
```

Edit: I just added the else if statement in the mix:

```
else if(money<0)
    combos
```

it got rid of the error but my output is 1500 something :( what is wrong with my logic?

Comment: You're second call to `recurs` (`recurs(money-coins.head,coins,combos+1)`) introduce an infinite loop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the correct solution based on your codes:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
  def recurs(m: Int, cs: List[Int], cnt: Int): Int =
      if(m < 0) cnt  //Not a change, keep cnt
      else if(cs.isEmpty) {
        if(m == 0) cnt + 1 else cnt // plus cnt if find a change
      }
      else recurs(m, cs.tail, cnt) + recurs(m-cs.head, cs, cnt)
  recurs(money, coins, 0)
}
```

Anyway, there is a short solution(But not efficient, you can cache the middle result to make it efficient.)

```
def countChange(m: Int, cs: List[Int]): Int = cs match {
  case Nil => if(m == 0) 1 else 0
  case c::rs => (0 to m/c) map (k => countChange(m-k*c,rs)) sum
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the solution as I don't understand it conceptually?

Answer (score 20):

The first solution in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15862778/458193) has a redundant last parameter [as noted by Paaro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061468/458193) so I wanted to get rid of it.   The second solution uses `map` which I wanted to avoid since it wasn't covered yet in the Week 1 or the Scala course I assume you're taking. Also, the second solution, as rightly noted by the author, would be way slower, unless it uses some memoization. Finally, [Paaro's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061468/458193) seems to have an unnecessary nested function.

So here's what I ended up with:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int =
  if (money < 0)
    0
  else if (coins.isEmpty)
    if (money == 0) 1 else 0
  else
    countChange(money, coins.tail) + countChange(money - coins.head, coins)
```

There is no need for braces here, as you can see.

I wonder if it could be further simplified.

Answer (score 3):

One can omit the cnt parameter, which is, in fact, never accumulated. The recurs function always returns either 0 or 1, so the optimized algorithm would be:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
  def recurs(m: Int, cs: List[Int]): Int =
      if(m < 0) 0  //Not a change, return 0
      else if(cs.isEmpty) {
        if(m == 0) 1 else 0 // 1 if change found, otherwise 0
      }
      else recurs(m, cs.tail) + recurs(m-cs.head, cs)
  if(money>0) recurs(money, coins) else 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The @Eastsun solution is good but it fails when money=0 due to it returns 1 instead of 0, but you can fix it easily:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
  def recurs(m: Int, cs: List[Int], cnt: Int): Int =
      if(m < 0) cnt  //Not a change, keep cnt
      else if(cs.isEmpty) {
        if(m == 0) cnt + 1 else cnt // plus cnt if find a change
      }
      else recurs(m, cs.tail, cnt) + recurs(m-cs.head, cs, cnt)
  if(money>0) recurs(money, coins, 0) else 0
}
```

Comment: I think it is reasonable to return 1 rather than 0 when money=0, since there is exact one way to change 0. Think about 0！=1 and 0-combinations is 1.

Comment: Well..in my exercise I was asked to return 0 in that scenario :)

Answer (score 1):

here is a DP approach to reduce a lot of re-calculation in recursive approach

```
object DP {
  implicit val possibleCoins = List(1, 5, 10, 25, 100)
  import collection.mutable.Map

  def countChange(amount: Int)(implicit possibleCoins: List[Int]) = {
    val min = Map((1 to amount).map (_->Int.MaxValue): _*)
    min(0) = 0
    for {
      i <- 1 to amount
      coin <- possibleCoins
      if coin <= i && min(i - coin) + 1 < min(i)
    } min(i) = min(i-coin) + 1
    min(amount)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = println(countChange(97))
}
```

see [DP from novice to advanced](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/) for algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Idea from https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/9e99f73b4241f42cc40a1fd890e72dbeda2df54f/src/main/scala/com/github/pathikrit/scalgos/DynamicProgramming.scala#L44

```scala
case class Memo[K,I,O](f: I => O)(implicit i2k:I=>K ) extends (I => O) {
  import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => Dict}
  val cache = Dict.empty[K, O]
  override def apply(x: I) = cache getOrElseUpdate (x, f(x))
}
def coinchange(s: List[Int], t: Int) = {
  type DP = Memo[ (Int, Int), (List[Int], Int),Seq[Seq[Int]]]
  implicit def encode(key: (List[Int], Int)):(Int,Int) = (key._1.length, key._2)

  lazy val f: DP = Memo {
    case (Nil, 0) => Seq(Nil)
    case (Nil, _) => Nil
    case (_, x) if x< 0  => Nil
    case (a :: as, x) => f(a::as, x - a).map(_ :+ a) ++ f(as, x)
  }

  f(s, t)
}
```