# Time Complexity of Counting Change

Tags: scala, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have a similar problem to link: [coin change algorithm in scala using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629721/coin-change-algorithm-in-scala-using-recursion)

The Code is recursive and looks like:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
    def count(capacity: Int, changes: List[Int]): Int = {
            if(capacity == 0) 1
            else if(capacity < 0) 0
            else if(changes.isEmpty && capacity >=1 )0
            else count(capacity, changes.tail) + count(capacity - changes.head, changes)
    }
count(money, coins)
}
```

My Questions is how to analyze the time complexity of this algorithm? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is form of tree recursion which grow exponentially with input. [SICP has very nice explanation about this](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.2).