# Counting change in Scala - Code doesn't print

Tags: scala

I am a beginner in Scala and in programming as such. Trying to shift to Data Science and am learning stuff on my own. I apologize if this is a very trivial question. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the main function here? I am trying to pass arguments in the countChange function but the code doesn't print anything. I have tried to look it up and understand, but I am totally lost and any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

```
object main {
  def countChange(money: Int, change: List[Int]): Int = {
    def totalWays(sum: Int, denomination: List[Int]): Int = {
      if (sum < 0) 0
      else
        if (sum == 0) 1
        else
          if (denomination.isEmpty && sum >= 0) 0
          else
           countChange(sum, denomination.tail) + countChange(sum-denomination.head,denomination) 
    }
    countChange(money, change.sortWith(_.compareTo(_) < 0))

  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val l = List(1,2)
    println(countChange(0,l))

}
}
```

Comment: Does it compile? This part doesn't seem right `change.sortWith(_.compareTo(_) < 0)`.

Comment: @pedrofurla : No, it doesn't! Oh! Can you please tell me what is wrong about it? Infact, I referenced this code from the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629721/coin-change-algorithm-in-scala-using-recursion

Comment: I plugged the code into my IDE (IntelliJ) and it seems to compile, but I noticed two things: 1) the `totalWays()` function is never called, and 2) the `countChange()` function is endlessly recursive; there is no bailout condition.

Comment: @jwvh : Ohh! Can you suggest how else I can go about this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details pointed in the comments by @jwvh are on track. It seems you copied some stuff from somewhere and you got lost in the way.
You don't need the `totalWays` inner function, since it implements already what you intended to do when calling `countChange`. So, you can simply unwrap it and rename the variables accordingly:

```
  def countChange(money: Int, denomination: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (money < 0) 0
    else if (money == 0) 1
    else if (denomination.isEmpty && money >= 0) 0
    else
      countChange(money, denomination.tail) + countChange(money - denomination.head, denomination)
  }
```

Also, you should be calling it with the initial amount and the list of denominations:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val l = List(1,2)
    println(countChange(3,l))
  } 
  // prints: 2
```

Comment: this is a good solution.  2 notes: if 'denomination' is empty this it does not matter what 'money' equals as you can't make change.  so the and statement isn't entirely correct.  also you have 2 statements both returning 0, they can be combined with an or statement.  the resulting code would be if-else if-else structure.

Comment: @ale64bit : Thank you so much! I see what you mean and it works perfectly! Thank you again! Also, even if I call it with money=0, it will still work as according to the code, I should get a 1. Thank you again!

Comment: @Max Wen : Yes, you are correct! I will try that! Thank you!

Comment: @MaxWen Valid advices :) Many things can be improved for sure; the point was to show the OP that the inner function wasn't necessary.

Comment: @ale64bit Sorry if that sounded nitpicky, I just did that same assignment yesterday so I couldn't help myself : D